# Why doesn`t a MultilineString layer display correctly

Tags: openlayers

onComponentDidMount, i run a function:

```
async mountPanoramasTiles() {
await this.fetchPanoramTracks();
this.drawRoadsLayer(this.panoramasTracksLayer);
```

This.drawRoadsLayer is next:

```
drawRoadsLayer(geoJSON) {
const { map, point } = this.props;

const geoVector = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJSON)
});

const tilesStyle = new ol.style.Style({
  stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: "blue",
    width: 1
  })
});

this.panoramasTracksLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: geoVector,
  style: tilesStyle
});
map.addLayer(this.panoramasTracksLayer);
```

I have a responce from server, that contains this info:

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"default_pano_shape.1","geometry":{"type":"MultiLineString","coordinates":[[[4162645.3515,7525239.799],[4162632.2158,7525249.9675],[4162622.9094,7525261.4838],[4162619.9373,7525275.8742],[4162622.5198,7525293.0397],[4162630.8019,7525307.0339],[4162644.0935,7525316.8061],[4162657.6077,7525321.504],[4162674.4211,7525324.5403]]]},"geometry_name":"geom","properties":{"objectid":1,"id":0,"shape_leng":127.622459436989288}
```

I use a geoJSON type of data, and all of the formats of coords of geoJSON and a map are the same(EPSG:3857), but instead of having long lines(roads), i see short intercepts.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in the geojson data. Paste the code at www.geojson.io and it will guide you when you will be missing some braces, array depth level, etc.
Good luck!